# Android -- Title bar invisible padding

Tags: android

So, I've seen several instances of padding being a problem in a custom title bar but this seems to be unique and I would love to see if anyone could shed some light on it.

Here's what I have:

[image]

There's padding to the right of the configure button that shouldn't be.  I want a little bit of padding in the end but, to prove a point, this is with no padding set.  Here's the layout for the custom title bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/titleImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="8dip"
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/customtitlebar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="COMPANY"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textColor="#205cc7"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="15px" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/configure" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I thought maybe the layout I gave a dummy id "container" was being cut off as well and the problem was outside this layout, but, when I change its background to red, it takes up the whole screen.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution short of hiding the OS title bar and making it a header for every screen layout?

Comment: You have to redesign that header as it is way to complex the way you've implemented it now. You are in a `RelativeLayout` why don't you make use of it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set [android:layout_alignParentRight="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentRight) to the LinearLayout which should be strechted to the right edge of the RelativeLayout.

Apart from that I agree to Octavian Damiean that your definition is to complex to receive the layout you want.

Answer (score 1):

This layout has the same problem that the first image does.  It uses alignParentRight and simplifies the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF" >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/titleImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/customtitlebar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="55dip"
        android:text="COMPANY"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textColor="#205cc7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="15px" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
        android:src="@drawable/configure" />
</RelativeLayout>
```